# QTextTable move QTextCursor to a determinated Cell

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtextcursor

I have a `QTextTable`, I do some actions in the table and I want two things:

- Return `QTextCursor` to cell (0,0)
- Or move `QTextCursor` to cell (row, columnn)

How can I do?

Comment: Use [QTextTable.cellAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexttable.html#cellAt-2) to get the current row/column and then use [QTextCursor.movePosition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#movePosition) to move the cursor relative to that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given `table` object of type `QTextTable` get desired cursor:

```
auto tableCell = table->cellAt(row, column);
auto cursor = tableCell.firstCursorPosition();
```

then [setTextCursor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setTextCursor) within edited `QTextEdit` object.

Comment: I mean QtCursor not cursor.

Comment: What do you mean by QtCursor? Example above is for setting QTextCursor position. Do you need to set QCursor (mouse pointer)?

Comment: I mean that I need to move the cursor to another cell of a QTableText, and I think what you propouse is to move cursor inside the cell.

Comment: First row of code in above example gets the desired table cell (your "another cell"), second row - gets the cursor of position for the begining of chosen cell. Then just call `yourEditor.setTextCursor(cursor);` to set the cursor to the begining of chosen (another) cell.

Comment: now I understand. Thank you so much!!! I will publicate and answer with your suggestion and ekhumoro.

Comment: in my real application I use a  [QTextDocument()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument-members.html), and this class  haven't .setTextCursor().

Comment: setTextCursor() is a QTextEdit method. There should be a QTextEdit object that displays the content of the QTextDocument, isn't it?

Comment: If it is not use `QTextCursor`'s method `setPosition()` with the position value of cursor obtained from `tableCell.firstCursorPosition()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241188/discussion-between-rbenet-and-retmas).

Answer (score 0):

Following @ekhumoro and @retmas suggestion I do this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor

#### EKHUMORO suggestion
def move_cursor(table_text,cursor,row_destiny,col_destiny):
    row=table_text.cellAt(cursor).row()
    while not row==row_destiny:
        if row<row_destiny:
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextRow)
        else:
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.PreviousRow)
        row=table_text.cellAt(cursor).row()  
    
    col=table_text.cellAt(cursor).column()
    while not col==col_destiny:
        if col<col_destiny:
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCell)    
        else:
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.PreviousCell)
        col=table_text.cellAt(cursor).column()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
       
    cursor=widget.textCursor()
    table_text=cursor.insertTable(10,10)

    # Format Table
    fmt = table_text.format()
    fmt.setWidth(QtGui.QTextLength(QtGui.QTextLength.PercentageLength, 100))
    table_text.setFormat(fmt)
    
    row=2
    col=5
    move_cursor(table_text,cursor,row,col)
    cursor.insertText('Cell {} {}'.format(row,col))   
    
    #### RETMAS SUGGESTION
    row=3
    column=6
    tableCell = table_text.cellAt(row, column)
    cursor = tableCell.firstCursorPosition() 
    widget.setTextCursor(cursor)
    cursor.insertText('Cell {} {}'.format(row,column))         

    widget.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

This works fine.